# Finding the right collection or writing my own way?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, collections, path-finding

I am busy building some path-finding. 
I currently use a Dictionary to hold all points to be evaluated, and then remove them when they are no longer needed. This is quite fast because i can address a point directly when adding and deleting and get O(1) performance out of that.

However at one point i need to evaluate all open points and find the best one based on a value inside each point-object. So we do a foreach loop through this dictionary, and need to evaluate each one until the very end. O(n) performance if i am correct?

So i am currently looking for a middle way. I want to be able to get any of my nodes with O(1), but i want to be more efficient in getting the point-object that i want. In this case i always always want the lowest value i find, so i could sort on that. However i cannot find a collection which can directly get on a key value and at the same time is sorting them on my value. (I would be sorting them upon adding a new one. Ideally by just walking through the list and adding it in between others where it is supposed to go based on that magic value)

Does anyone have any idea what the best collection would be, or am i better off writing a sort of linked list thing which i can customly manipulate? As in, each point-object holds a reference to the next point-object, so i can add one in between by just altering 1 reference in the chain. I could also find the best next to evaluate due to it always being the first in the chain.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Smiley

Comment: And what's the problem to use two dictionaries? one where the key is the current one, and the other, where the key is your "magic value" so you can locate objects using different criterias and still get O(1) performance?

Comment: Well the 2nd dictionary would still be a dictionary, therefor unsorted. Therefor not really helping my current situation at all? And probably not best memory wise, but i wouldn't mind such solution if i could guarantee speed that way.

Comment: You can still sort it using a SortedSet and then you can get a subset of data from the second dictionary.

Comment: For some reason SortedSet has O(log n) lookup efficiency, even though it works with a key like a dictionary. It is better then O(n) if i am correct, but still i wonder why it is not O(1) is it uses the key.